# C# client and Java server

Tags: c#, java

I have developed a retail EPOS solution in C# which runs on tills. I would like this to interface with a back-end Java server. The Java server will be used for running all back-office tasks such as reports.

What is the best method to get a C# client and a Java server talking to each other? Of course, if this were a sole Java setup, then RMI would be used.

I have a gut feeling that a web service is best here, but I am lost to what type of web service I'd be looking for.

I had a crazy "bad" idea that I could put a php script on the server which the C# client could call using HTTP and Curl (or C#'s equivalent) and send arguments via GET or POST. However this would be put a total disconnection between the java "back-end" server and C# client.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be a webservice (SOAP), Java and dotNet provide ample support...

Comment: Looks like soap is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

We has this same issue, and found that a Webservice was indeed the best way to go. The speed has been very satisfactory for large scale usage too.

We made the service on the Java side of things, and created a Class file for the C# system from the WSDL endpoint using the Visual Studio command-line line tool "WSDL.exe".

[MSDN Visual Studio WSDL Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx)